# Producing readable coloured terminal output

Tags: terminal, colors

I want to produce coloured output from a terminal program. My problem is that some people use a 'light' terminal theme, while others use a 'dark' one.

Is there a standard way of ensuring that my output will be readable for all "reasonable" terminal configurations (for some definition of reasonable)?

Comment: Give a settings (dark, light), and use normal colours. People with light colours have probably redefined some colours to be more readable (I use an orange instead of yellow, and a "darker cyan" instead of cyan (and so on). But also on dark terminal not all colours are readable: different terminal uses different colours. Programs that uses a lot of colours, usually have a customizable interface (editors, irc clients, etc.)

Comment: I've seen tooling to determine if the background is dark or light to figure out a "theme" and use different colour sets for each; for example, for Go, [like this](https://github.com/muesli/termenv/blob/v0.13.0/termenv.go#L49).